# Cairo.Matrix dll gives an Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using the **Cairo.Matrix dll** in my monoandroid application to load the some System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matix Class Methods it works fine at build time  but at run time the Matrix class from Cairo.Matrix gives an error **"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**
                 when I intialize the Cairo.Matrix Class error is **"Exception in loading dicom filelibcairo-2.dll."**

This below code I am trying..........

```
using System; 

using System.Drawing; 

using Medsynaptic.Common;

using Medsynaptic.Imaging1.Mathematics; 

**using Matrix = Cairo.Matrix;**

public class SpatialTransform : ISpatialTransform 

    { 

private Cairo.Matrix _cumulativeTransform; 

        private Cairo.Matrix _transform; 

public PointF ConvertToDestination(PointF sourcePoint) 

        { 

            double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;         

            this.CumulativeTransform.TransformPoint(ref x, ref y);      

            PointF point = new PointF((float)x, (float)y); 

            return point; 
        }
```

**Here it show Null Ref Exception:Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

```
public Cairo.Matrix CumulativeTransform       
    {        

        get 

        {      

            Calculate(); 

            return _cumulativeTransform; 

        } 

    } 

 protected virtual void Calculate() 

    { 

        if (!this.RecalculationRequired) 

            return;
```

**ERROR @ if condition:- Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

```
        if (_cumulativeTransform == null) 

            _cumulativeTransform = new Cairo.Matrix(); 


       // _cumulativeTransform.Reset(); 

        _cumulativeTransform.InitIdentity(); 
} 

}
```

this is android debugger show an output with error Error In loading **libcairo-2.dll**

```
On Create Call

Picture box OnAttachedToWindow.

 display.Height 430

  firstRowHeight 43

  pictureBox.DisplayHeight 301

Displaying image /mnt/sdcard/Images/Series1/1.2.840.113619.2.22.287.1.20040913.195606.dcm

Request garbage collector to initiate.

Presentation Image created.

 Calling invalidate in Render Mode

Renderer will take care of it.

 Calling DrawSceneGraph

Error In loading
```

**libcairo-2.dll**

```
 Picture box on draw called

 Displayed medsynaptic.medsynapse/desktopexecutable.Activity1: +1m10s925ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the inclusion of `Mono.Cairo.dll` was a mistake; it can't work, as it depends upon the native libcairo.so, which Android doesn't provide. `Mono.Cairo.dll` will be removed in the next release.